# What's the interpretation of setting small singular values to $0$ in SVD

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, svd

Given a linear transformation $A$, where $\dim(A) = m \times n$, we can decompose it using SVD:
\begin{align}
A = U\Sigma V^T
\end{align}
to a series of transformations, that is inverse rotation, scaling and rotation (transformation from sphere to ellipsoid).
Interpretation of $A$ is obviously a transformation from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$. Let's assume that there are $k$ very small singular values in $\Sigma$. Although I feel that setting these $k$ values to $0$ is the right thing to do, I don't really know how it is justified in terms of reducing dimensionality. If semi-minor axis of an ellipse is short (because of the $\approx 0$ singular value), what does it really mean in terms of transformation, and what does it tell us about $A$?

Comment: It computes the best low rank approximation to $A$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation#Proof_of_Eckart%E2%80%93Young%E2%80%93Mirsky_theorem_(for_spectral_norm)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks, I know that and the fact that SVD minimizes the Frobenius norm, but that's not what I am asking about.